# Is it true that for all real numbers, there exists an integer smaller than it?

Tags: logic, integers

I cannot conclusively answer this as I have two different opinions:

1. It is false considering that the set of integers is a subset of the reals and that the “smallest” integer is also a real, hence there is a real number which does not have a smaller integer
2. It is true, considering that there are infinite integers, so there is always an integer smaller than a real

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: argument $1$ is false.  It is not true that every subset of the reals has a least element.   the integers, in particular, have no least element.

Comment: How would u prove it?

Comment: Should have said:  your argument $2$ is also false, though the conclusion is correct.  To see that $2$ is false note that there are infinitely many positive integers but there is no positive integer smaller than $0$, say.

Comment: If all you are looking for is intuition... then pick a real number, any real number.  After I've heard your number and am given a brief moment to think, I'll be able to say an integer smaller than what you just said.  Let's try a few times... If you say $5.8$ I might say $5$.  If you say $-\pi$ I might say $-4$.  If you say $-10000000000000.37$, I might say $-10000000000001$.  Do you need more examples to see what I'm doing?  Can you see that regardless what you say for your real number I can always pick an integer less than it?

Comment: As for "how would u prove it?" if you are talking about how the integers has no least element... suppose for contradictory purposes that it *did* have a least element, $\ell$.  Then, consider $\ell-1$ which we understand will also be an integer and in particular will be smaller than $\ell$, contradicting the notion that $\ell$ were in fact least.

Comment: Does "smaller than" mean "less than", or are we talking about magnitude, so that $0$ is smaller than either $8$ or $-3$? Assuming the first, the link provided by lulu is a good one. Assuming the second, $0$ ends up being "smaller" than any real number (except for $0$, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ but $x \notin\mathbb{Z}, [x]$ is an integer smaller than $x.$

If $x \in \mathbb{Z}, x-1$ is an integer smaller than $x.$